# Can we find the cohomology of any manifold homeomorphic to a manifold $M$ if we know the de Rham cohomology of $M$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have the two sphere $S^2$ which has de Rham cohomology $H^k_{dR} (S^2) =\begin{cases} \mathbb{R} & k=0,2 \\ 0 & k=1 \end{cases}$.
The two sphere is homeomorphic to a tetrahedron.
Also by de Rham's theorem the cohomology of the two sphere is the same as de Rham cohomology and since cohomology is invariant under homeomorphism, the tetrahedron has the same cohomology as the two sphere.
Is this correct?

Does this argument work in general, that is, if I have a manifold $M$ whose de Rham cohomology is known, is the (singular) cohomology of any manifold homeomorphic to $M$ the same as the de Rham cohomology of $M$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. For a proof see the [book by Bott and Tu](https://books.google.com/books/about/Differential_Forms_in_Algebraic_Topology.html?id=pEO9SAAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description) (together with a proof in any algebraic topology book that singular homology is a homeomorphism invariant).

Comment: Let me stress that the de Rham cohomology is only isomorphic to the singular cohomology with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients, which is a weaker invariant than the singular cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients. Most people would probably assume you mean $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients when you just say "singular cohomology" without specifying coefficients. The singular cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient is of course also a homeomorphism invariant, but it is not determined by the singular cohomology with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients (and hence also not by teh de Rham cohomology).